# Fetch data for ag-grid in Remix

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, remix.run

I'm learning [Remix.run](https://remix.run/) and trying to figure out how to face some requirements
in advance. According to the documentation there is something called [Resource Routes](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/resource-routes). But seems that a `Resource Route` need to be linked from a Link component:

```js
<Link to="pdf" reloadDocument>
    View as PDF
</Link>
```

I can't found any example showing how to create a simple route that can return data for a grid component, for example ag-grid.

There is any way to do this inside Remix or I will need to implement an external endpoint?

Comment: As I understand you need to load some data and use it to generate the grid component, is that it? In that case, maybe you could use the loader function to fetch the data.

Comment: What @amimaro said. Plus you can find an example from the docs for a resource route https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/resource-routes#creating-resource-routes

Comment: Did you solve it? If not, resource routes are normal URLs which you can use as any other URL, they can return basically whatever you want, in this article I explain how I used 2 resource routes to generate og:images https://www.canrau.com/en/dynamically-generate-ogimage-using-remix maybe that helps, if not please add more details and feel free to ping me

Answer (score 2):

AG Grid wrote a blog post about this not too long ago. Here is the article: https://blog.ag-grid.com/using-ag-grid-react-ui-with-remix-run/.

First, set up a resource route using Remix's conventions outlined here: https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/resource-routes#creating-resource-routes

The resource route should export only a loader function that retrieves the data you want to load into the table.

**Note**: This example also uses logic for infinite scrolling

`app/routes/posts/$id/postsGridData.ts`

```
import type { LoaderFunction } from 'remix';
import { db } from '~/utils/db.server'; // Prisma ORM being used

export const loader: LoaderFunction = ({ request }) => {
  const from = Number(new URL(request.url).searchParams.get("from"));
  const to = Number(new URL(request.url).searchParams.get("to"));

  if (from >= 0 && to > 0) {
    const posts = await db.post.findMany({
      skip: from,
      take: to - from,
      select: {
        id: true,
        title: true,
        updatedAt: true,
        author: {
          select: {
            email: true,
            name: true,
          },
        },
      },
    });

    return posts;
  }
  return [];
}
```

Next, in the route with your AGGridReact component, you'll add the following:

- A Remix Fetcher to get the data from your resource route without a route change
- An `onGridReady` function that loads the next batch of data
- Some local state to manage the fetching logic
- A `datasource` to plug into AG Grid
- A `useEffect` function to trigger when the fetcher has loaded
- AgGridReact component with added parameters `rowModelType` and `onGridReady`

`app/routes/posts.tsx`

```
import { useFetcher } from 'remix';
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import AgGridStyles from "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import AgThemeAlpineStyles from "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";

export default function PostsRoute() {
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);
  const [getRowParams, setGetRowParams] = useState(null);
  const posts = useFetcher();
  
  const onGridReady = useCallback((params) => {
    const datasource = {
    getRows(params) {
      if (!isFetching) {
        posts.load(`/posts?from=${params.startRow}&to=${params.endRow}`);

        setGetRowParams(params);
        setIsFetching(true);
      }
    },
  };

  params.api.setDatasource(datasource);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
  // The useEffect hook in this code will trigger when the fetcher has 
  // loaded new data. If a successCallback is available, it’ll call it, 
  // passing the loaded data and the last row to load
  if (getRowParams) {
    const data = posts.data || [];

    getRowParams.successCallback(
      data,
      data.length < getRowParams.endRow - getRowParams.startRow
        ? getRowParams.startRow
        : -1
    );
  }

  setIsFetching(false);
  setGetRowParams(null);
}, [posts.data, getRowParams]);

  const columnDefs = [/* Your columnDefs */];

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
      <AgGridReact
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        rowModelType="infinite"
        onGridReady={onGridReady}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```